# Maintain parent child relationship between two form

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog

In my windows forms application, I have two forms, `mainForm` and `recordForm`. in main form there is some textboxes and buttons , and on a click of particular button I want to show the `recordForm`.

But I want when the second form is opened, then user can't perform any operation (like filling textboxes etc) until second form is closed. I tried this:

```
private void tsCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            recordForm customers = new recordForm();
            customers.Show();
        }
```

tsCustomer is button on `mainForm`. How can i do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your code from:

```
customers.Show();
```

to:

```
customers.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 1):

How about [Form.ShowDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa335145%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)?

From MSDN Site : Shows the form as a modal dialog box with no owner window.

This does not effectively relates two forms of your application. But showing the second form in modal form is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
customers.ShowDialog();
```

in order for the customer form to be modal.

Comment: You can delete this answer, because same answer already exists.